# Add curl library C++

Tags: c++, curl

I'm little new in coding. I want to add libcurl library to my visual studio project , I think I do it right but I'm not sure . how ever I have some errors in header missing

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <libxml/HTMLparser.h>
```

I add the library with References->Manage Nuget packages->and libcurl.net library

but still I have errors on compile. also I have a warning too maybe problem is in warning from

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The 'packages' element is not declared. Project3    C:\Users\Pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project3\Project3\packages.config 2
```

and here is my some part of the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <libxml/HTMLparser.h>

//
//  Case-insensitive string comparison
//

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define COMPARE(a, b) (!_stricmp((a), (b)))
#else
#define COMPARE(a, b) (!strcasecmp((a), (b)))
#endif

//
//  libxml callback context structure
//

struct Context
{
    Context() : addTitle(false) { }

    bool addTitle;
    std::string title;
};

//
//  libcurl variables for error strings and returned data

static char errorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
static std::string buffer;
```

also I find many same topics and read them well but I don't know where is my problem.

also for an another question , my goal is get an simple string from an online page ! do you know a better and easier way to get an string??

Comment: am I add the library in true way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide the path to the header files of `libcurl` for the compiler (prescribe it at `Project->Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories`) and to the libcurl.lib (it is paired with libcurl.dll) for the linker (prescribe it at `Project->Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`).